# Domain URL is not resolving Openshift router

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have setup an application in openshift and it is accessible through https://test-uat-ex.com which is a route for the application in openshift.

I have registered a domain called example.com and added https://test-uat-ex.com as a CNAME record to newly registered domain.

I am able to access the application using openshift route URL. But, when I access the newly created domain call example.com, I am getting

> Service unavailable 503 error.

Comment: What OpenShift cluster are you using? If you are using OpenShift Online free starter tier, custom domain names aren't supported. You need to be using the paid tier to have custom domain names.

Comment: We are using Openshift Enterprise.

Comment: And you created a new route in OpenShift for the service corresponding to your application, with the hostname of the route set to your registered ``example.com`` domain name? It is not enough just to map DNS using a CNAME, you have to set up the routing layer in OpenShift to know that the custom domain name should be routed to your application.

Comment: Thank You very much Graham!!! I will check the routing layer.